# Какие есть программы на Ubuntu для создания gif через терминал?

Tags: php, node.js

Какие вообще есть варианты из программ создающих анимированный гиф, с возможностью их запуска с параметрами из терминала, например через nodejs или php exec?
Возможно кто то посоветует хорошо оптимизированную програму, чтоб не сильно грузило сервер. Мне пока знакомы только GMagick и IMagick именно как отдельное ПО.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ffmpeg - https://medium.com/@colten_jackson/doing-the-gif-thing-on-debian-82b9760a8483

пачка статичных изображений конвертируется в gif в 2 шага

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i image%d.jpg video.avi
ffmpeg -i video.avi -pix_fmt rgb24 -loop_output 0 out.gif
```

Comment: Спасибо то что нужно!!! отличная программа. Там и в 1 шаг есть, сразу из набора картинок в гиф.

Answer (score 0):

QGifer - это отличный инструмент для создания анимированных GIF-файлов в Ubuntu Linux. Данное приложение отличается от других тем, что оно написано на Qt и позволяет конвертировать небольшие видеоролики в GIF-анимации.

sudo apt-get install libav-tools

Comment: не подскажите, пожалуйста, а из кадров jpg\png собрать там есть возможность?

Comment: мы делали только из видео в командной строке

Comment: а понял! все равно спасибо большое за ответ :) 
изучу эту программу может все таки у неё есть возможность собирать из кадров